# Repeat colnames in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to repeat a set of column names. Sometimes I'll have 1 set of columns to name and some other times I'll have 4 sets of columns to names. For example:

1 set of column names:

```
 r    a
```

2 set of column names:

```
r    a     r    a
```

I've tried using this for loop:

```
 for(cnt in 1:numSetCol){
    colnames(data[,cnt]) <- "r"
    colnames(data[,cnt+1]) <- "a"
    cnt <- cnt + 2 

}
```

I get the error:  attempt to set colnames on object with less than two dimensions.

Any help on how to do this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: `colnames(data) <- rep(c("a", "r"), 2)`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense - you can't address the colnames anymore by name (`x$r` only addresses the first column called `r`). But anyway, try `for(cnt in 1:(numSetCol-2)){...}`

Comment: Please take some time to read [An introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), the first document [listed here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Answer (score 2):

You should take @vaettchen's point seriously; you won't be able to access variables by column names if you do this.  I suggest you add an number to each name to better index your variables.  This can be done like so:

```
> dframe   <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60), ncol=6))
> cletters <- rep(c("r","a"), times=3)
> cindexes <- rep(c(1,2,3),   each=2)
> cnames   <- paste(cletters, cindexes, sep="")
> cnames
[1] "r1" "a1" "r2" "a2" "r3" "a3"
> colnames(dframe) <- cnames
> colnames(dframe)
[1] "r1" "a1" "r2" "a2" "r3" "a3"
```

---

For what it's worth, your `for` loop code is flawed.  You are mixing the way you would code a `for` loop with the way you would code a `while` loop.  Each time the script goes to the top of the `for` loop, `cnt` is reset and your `cnt <- cnt + 2` statement is wiped out.  Consider:

```
> numSetCol <- 6
> for(cnt in 1:numSetCol){
+   print(cnt)
+   cnt <- cnt + 2 
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
```

However, using loops is not the best strategy here.  I recommend you also follow @Henrik's advice and read the introduction to R manual to start learning more about the basics of R.

Answer (score 1):

```
mydata<-mtcars
names(mydata)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

x<-rep(names(mydata),2)
> x
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb" "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"  
[21] "gear" "carb"
```